# Hiberanate failing to save joining column

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, rest, spring-boot

I am trying to save a list of directors of a company whenever i create a new merchant, thus i have a @ManyToOne relationship  between Director and Merchant respectively.

Thus far i have managed to get it to save the list of directors and the merchant when i do a POST. However when i do a GET request i do not get back the directors, the list comes back empty. When i check in the database, the joining column is empty as shown in the image but the rest of the data is present. How can i solve this issue?

[image]

This is my code :

**Director.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Directors")
public class Director {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long directorID;

@Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL}) 
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "merchantNumber")
private Merchant merchant;

@NotBlank
private String name;

@NotBlank
private String surname;

 public Director() {

    }

public Director(long directorID, Merchant merchant, String name, String surname) {
    this.directorID = directorID;
    this.merchant = merchant;
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
}

...

Getters and setters
```

**DirectorRepository.java**

```
public interface DirectorRepository  extends CrudRepository<Director, String> {

}
```

**Merchant.java**

```
public class Merchant {
 @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int merchantNumber;

@NotBlank
private String merchantID;

@NotBlank
private String businessName;

@Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL}) 
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "merchant")
 private List<Director> directors;

@NotBlank
private String userName;



public Merchant(int merchantNumber, String merchantID, String businessName, List<Director> directors, String userName ) {
        this.merchantNumber = merchantNumber;
        this.merchantID = merchantID;
        this.businessName = businessName;
        this.directors = directors;
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    ...

    Getter and setters
```

**MerchantService.java**

```
   public ResponseMerchantQuery createMerchant(Merchant merchant) {

           if( merchant == null || merchant.getMerchantID()== null){
              throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Empty", "Missing Data Exception");
          } else {
              merchant.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(merchant.getPassword()));
              merchantRepository.save(merchant);
              String merchantNum = Long.toString(merchant.getMerchantNumber());
              return new ResponseMerchantQuery(merchantNum, "Merchant Created Successfully");
          }
    }
```

**MerchantController.java**

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/api/merchants")
    public ResponseMerchantQuery createMerchant(@Valid @RequestBody Merchant merchant){

     System.out.println("size of merchnat " + merchant.getDirectors().size());
       return  merchantService.createMerchant(merchant);

     }
```

Comment: You simply forgot to set the `merchant` field of each of the Directors. Also, cascde=ALL on a ManyToOne makes no sense. You don't want to delete the merchant when you delete one of its directors. Not to mention that, since you also set cascade=ALL on the other side, this would in turn delete all the other directors of the merchant.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, you said in your answer i should set the merchant field where?

Comment: Where you think it's the most appropriate. I personally never use an entity as a request body. An entity represents my persistence model. What I receive represents the data entered in a form, which may represent one or several parts of one or several entities, using formats that usuelly differ, and that should not be tightly coupled to my persistence model. So, when I create the entities from the data I receive, that's where I make sure I correctly initialize the state of my entities.

Comment: i am still a noob in development using spring-boot hence the poor standards,  however thank u

Comment: Would you mind showing me an example of where i can set the merchant field.

Comment: `merchant.getDirectors().stream().forEach(director -> director.setMerchant(merchant));`

Comment: Now it saves but when i do a get request it throws Expected ',' instead of ''

Comment: I'm not a wizard I can't tell why you get an error without seeing the stack trace of the error and the relevant code.

Comment: the error is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed

Comment: This is a different problem. So ask another question, **providing all the requested details**.

Comment: turns out there was a  infinite recursion going on and all i needed to do was add @JsonIgnore to the get method that gets called when i do a get request. Please add erchant.getDirectors().stream().forEach(director -> director.setMerchant(merchant));  as an answer so that i accept